# Mysql trigger with concatenation in variable doesn't work

Tags: mysql, triggers, concatenation

I made a trigger in Mysql, but for some reason the result of the concatenation is always zero. What am I missing?

```
BEGIN

IF NEW.weight < OLD.weight THEN
SET @description = CONCAT('You lost ', OLD.weight - NEW.weight, ' kgs');
ELSE
SET @description = CONCAT('You gained ', NEW.weight - OLD.weight, ' kgs');
END IF;
INSERT INTO History
VALUES (NEW.user_id, 'weight', @description, null);

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "is always zero"?

`CONCAT` should return a string value, or a NULL.

Based on the code provided, the result from the `CONCAT` expression gets assigned to the user-defined variable `@description`.

We do notice that the `INSERT` doesn't specify the columns to be inserted into. Is it possible that the values you're inserting aren't "lining up" with the columns in the table.

Specify the names of the columns, in order corresponding the order of the provided values

```
INSERT INTO History (col3, col1, col4, col2)
VALUES (NEW.user_id, 'weight', @description, null)
```

And make sure the column we're inserting the string value into is character type, and not numeric. (MySQL will silently do implicit conversion of strings to numeric, ... as a simple demonstration of the behavior consider:

```
SELECT 'foo' + 0     AS c1
     , '123abc' + 0  AS c2
```

---

If that's not the problem, then ...

If you were meaning that the result of `NEW.weight - OLD.weight` evaluates to zero, that will happen whenever the `NEW.` and `OLD.` values of `weight` are equal.

If `weight` can be NULL, consider checking other conditions, for example, using the MySQL `CASE` statement (available in MySQL stored program, not to be confused with the `CASE` expression.)

```
CASE
  WHEN NEW.weight < OLD.weight 
  THEN SET @description = CONCAT('You lost ', OLD.weight - NEW.weight, ' kgs');

  WHEN NEW.weight > OLD.weight
  THEN SET @description = CONCAT('You gained ', NEW.weight - OLD.weight, ' kgs');
  WHEN NEW.weight = OLD.weight
  THEN SET @description = 'Weight is unchanged';
  ELSE SET @description = 'NEW and/or OLD weight IS NULL';
END
```

For debugging, consider saving those values in user-defined variables (so you can query the variables after the trigger is fired, from the same session).

Or consider adding the values to the description message,

```
CONCAT(...,' ow=',IFNULL(OLD.weight,'NULL'),' nw=',IFNULL(NEW.weight,'NULL'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough explanation. What I meant by "the result of the concatenation is always zero", is that the content of @description was always '0' in the table History. But I found out what the problem was... for some in-explainable reason, the column for the value of description was set to DOUBLE and not TEXT or VARCHAR. So that's why it entered a 0. I feel so stupid now.

Comment: Just as I suspected ... implicit data conversion of string to numeric. (Not enough information in the question to actually diagnose the problem, but that was my guess.)